# order event posts by multiple custom fields

Tags: customization

My event date data is in 3 separate custom fields and I need to sort by entire date, including day, month, year. Right now it's sorting by month only. How can I change it to sort by not just month but full date? Here's my code:

```
$arguments = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'eventsmonth',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        ),
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'eventsday',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        ),
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'eventsyear',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value'
         )
  ),
    'meta_key'   =>  'eventsmonth',  // sorting by month
    'orderby'    =>  'meta_value_num', // numeric value
    'order'      =>  'ASC' 
);
```

Comment: Did you create this custom post type for event or you are using any 3rd party plugin for this? You can check their plugin manual.

Comment: This is bad design - the date should be stored in one field in a format that can easily compared such as Unix timestamp or YYYY/MM/DD - I would look to try and do that and your queries will be much simpler.

Comment: you're right, it's not ideal—I'm using a themeforest theme. But there's really no reason for their separation. I'll redo the custom field to one and then sort by that one field. Thanks